# Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors for hermitian matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find eigenvalues and normalized eigenvectors of $
    A =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    0 & 3i \\
    -3i & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$

I found that that the eigenvalues are $3$ and $-3$

For the eigenvalue 3,

$
    \left [ \begin{matrix}
    0 & 3i \\
    -3i & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$ $
    \left [ \begin{matrix}
    x_{11} \\
    x_{21} \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$ = $
    3\left [ \begin{matrix}
    x_{11} \\
    x_{21} \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$

Since $\frac{x_{11}}{x_{21}} = i $

The first eigenvector is $
    x_1 =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    i \\
    1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$

Now, for the next eigenvalue $-3$,

I did the same thing,
$
    \left [ \begin{matrix}
    0 & 3i \\
    -3i & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$ $
    \left [ \begin{matrix}
    x_{12} \\
    x_{22} \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$ = $
    -3\left [ \begin{matrix}
    x_{12} \\
    x_{22} \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$

And since $\frac{x_{12}}{x_{22}} = -i$

Therefore the second eigenvector is $x_2 =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    -i \\
    1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$

Since matrix A is a Hermitian matrix: $x_1^+ x_2 = 0$

Checking it: I get $-(i^2) + 1 =2$ which does not equal to 0, where have I went wrong?

It seems like the 2nd eigenvector should be $x_2 =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    i \\
    1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$  but it does not make sense with my calculations

Comment: $x_1^+x_2=x_2^tx_2=(-i)^2+1=0.$ I think you forgot to take the conjugate complex coordinates when calculating $x_1^+$ (often also denoted by $x_1^*$).

Answer (score 3):

I believe the mistake lies in you forgetting to take the complex conjugate of $x_1$

Upon taking the complex conjugate of $x_1$, $x_1$ becomes $\begin{bmatrix} -i \\1 \end{bmatrix}$, and taking $x_1^+x_2$ now gives $(-i)^2 + 1 = 0$

Answer (score 2):

As commented 90 min ago:
$$x_1^+x_2=x_2^tx_2=(-i)^2+1=0.$$
I think you forgot to take the conjugate complex coordinates when calculating the [conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) $x_1^+$
(often also denoted by $x_1^*$
).

Comment: I am aware some moderators don't like answers to "poor quality" questions or "duplicate" answers, but this one showed sufficient efforts, and I did not succeed in finding some duplicate (even an "abstract" one). Please warn me if you find some.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're getting marked as duplicate for the [only other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4665678/705600) here. How is your answer different?

Comment: That other answer is a little less informative, and should anyway be considered as a duplicate of my prior comment above, which (believing it would not be welcomed) I strived from editing as a true answer until I discovered it was copied.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that the initial comment was from you. In that case I think you're right, this should be accepted.